# Master-Detail - Different cells to different UiTablevIewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, master-detail

Im having a problem connecting the different tableViewCells to different UiTableViewControllers. The first cellrow gets connected to the right TableViewController but after that cant get any further because I really dont know how to set the "else if" statement here.

Thanks in advance!

Please see the .m(master):

```
#import "GuideTableViewController.h"
#import "GuideDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "GuideDetailTableViewController2.h"
#import "GuideDetailTableViewController3.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface GuideTableViewController (){
    NSArray *guide;
    NSMutableData *weatherResponseData;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgHeader;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImgTitle;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImgWeather;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnMap;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LabelWeather;

@end

@implementation GuideTableViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



//JSON method
- (void) loadJSON{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //code
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropbox.com/u/100670549/test.json"]];

        NSError *error;

        if (data)
        {

            guide = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

            for (NSDictionary *dictionary in guide){
                //NSLog([dictionary description]);
            }


        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not load data");
        }




            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // code
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });


    });


    }




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Call json

    [self loadJSON];

    [self loadWeather];







    //set background
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];

    //rounded corners

    [self.tableView.layer setCornerRadius:9.0];

    [self.ImgWeather.layer setCornerRadius:9.0];






}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//TableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 3;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    NSDictionary *dict = [guide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}


//To detailView

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showStay"]){
        GuideDetailTableViewController *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *index = sender;
        NSDictionary *dict = [guide objectAtIndex:index.row];

        tvc.stay = dict;


    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEat"]){
        GuideDetailTableViewController2 *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *index = sender;
        NSDictionary *dict = [guide objectAtIndex:index.row];

        tvc.eat = dict;
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDo"]){
        GuideDetailTableViewController3 *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *index = sender;
        NSDictionary *dict = [guide objectAtIndex:index.row];

        tvc.todo = dict;
    }


}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showStay" sender:indexPath];


}


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];

    //ta bort markeringen när man går tillbaka till master från detailView.
    [cell setSelected:NO];


    //Hide navbar
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}


//Show navbar in detailView
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];   
}






@end
```

Comment: What does your code do at the moment? What do you want it to do? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Also, please accept answers if they helper you with your problem. Read the Stackoverflow FAQ.

Comment: Hi, when I click n the first cell in the MasterTableView I come to the  right DetailTableView. The problem is the other cells I have in the Master. I want to connect them to different DetailTableViews.

Comment: So are you attempting to have three rows in a single table that all link to different UIViewControllers when they are clicked?
Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Daniel, improve your question rather than just tacking stuff on in comments.

Comment: Joel: Yes thats exactly what Im trying. Im using storyboards yes. Occulos: Im new to this so sorry...will learn.